# Where does Zathura store bookmarks in Linux?

Tags: linux, pdf-reader

Where does `zathura` store bookmarks in `linux` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `~/.local/share/zathura/bookmarks`, for example:

```
# nothing

[/home/ja/ti/dp83867ir.pdf]
here=30;0.5;0.22692307692307692;
```

Notice that it's specified by the [`XDG standard`](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).